# Let $f:[0,a]\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ be a continuous function such that $f(t)\leq e^{\int_{0}^{t}f(s)ds}-1$ for all $t\in[0,a]$. Prove that $f\equiv0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $f:[0,a]\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ be a continuous function such that $$f(t)\leq e^{\int_{0}^{t}f(s)ds}-1$$ for all $t\in[0,a]$. Prove that $f\equiv0$.

I have thought like this: Assume $F(t)=\int_{0}^{t}f(s)ds\implies F'(t)=f(t)$ . Then $F'(t)\leq e^{F(t)}-1$. Now how can proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $$ F'(t) \leq e^{F(t)} -1$$ rearranging and multiplying we get the inequality
$$e^{-F(t)-t} (F'(t)+1) \leq e^{-t}$$
$$ \implies \frac {d}{dt} e^{-F(t)-t} \geq \frac {d}{dt} e^{-t}$$
$$\implies  e^{-F(t)-t} \geq e^{-t} $$ 
$$ \implies e^{F(t)} \leq 1$$
$$\implies F(t)\leq 0$$
But we know $F$ is non negative and hence $F\equiv 0$
So $$ f\equiv 0$$